# Not able to access Web API method using XMLHttpRequest but using Restclient Plugin and etc

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, restful-authentication

I have run in to a problem. Please help with your expertise.

I am developing web solution for a company. They have provided me Web API Method (REST). This API is in their domain. I am too access this from my domain.  Even client has also already whitelisted my domain.

I am trying to  call this method using below. But no luck. I am getting this below error.

Error NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied

function GetCustomerInfo()
{
    var Url = "http://webapi.company.com/vx.x/customer/get?format=xml&mobile=9876543210" ;
    myXmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myXmlHttp.withCredentials  = true;
    myXmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
    myXmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, true,"UID","PWD");
    myXmlHttp.send();
}

function ProcessRequest() 
{

```
if(this.readyState == this.DONE) 
{
        if(this.status == 200 && this.responseXML != null ) 
    {
        alert ("Received Resoponse from Server");
        }
    else
    {
        alert ("Some Problem");
    }
    }
```

}

I am able to access this method from RESTClient in firefox plugin.
Even I am able to access this method copying credentials in URL as below in browser address bar. I get anticipated response XML

http://UID:PWD@webapi.company.com/vx.x/customer/get?format=xml&mobile=9876543210

Please enlighten me where I am wrong. Perhaps JSONP can come to my help. But why i am not able to access this API using XMLHttpRequest.

Regards
Rajul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same origin policy of the browser does not allow you to send XMLHttpRequests to a different domain. The reason you can access it through a firefox plugin or the address bar is that the same origin policy is not applied there.

You are right, JSONP could solve your problem, although you may run into trouble because you do not control the serverside.

In response to your comment: In order to use JSONP effectively, the server will need to return not only the data you need in JSON format, but also javascript code to invoke a callback when the request is done. If you do not control the data that is returned, you can not add the necessary code for this. The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) article gives a good example for the general case.

I have never used CORS, thus can not give you much information on it. It seems like a better solution, but I imagine it is not incredibly compatible across browsers. Also, as I understand it, you will need control of the server as well, as it seems to require additional HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain more  on this "You may run into trouble because you do not control the server side.". May be some web references you can share. that will be great.

Comment: How about CORS? Can it come to my help?

Comment: @Rajul: See the edits. It looks to me like you have two options. First: Ask the client to add either the needed header for CORS or the necessary code for JSONP. Second, if they are not willing to do that: Send an XMLHttpRequest to your own domain, where your own web server acts as a proxy by sending a request to their Api and forwarding the result to you. The server is not affected by the same origin policy.